# Roslaunch machine tag on include

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run a launch file on a remote machine. Is it possible to specify a machine for an  call in a roslaunch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86931/roslaunch-machine-tag-on-include/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2013-10-03

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No this is not possible, this is nodes which are run remotely. On the opposite there is no computation linked to the XML files so there is no mean in launching one remotely. Therefore, all includes are local to your machine.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cellard0or](https://answers.ros.org/users/27123/cellard0or/) on 2017-04-12**:
As @Girmi 's answer shows, there actually is a way to tell subsequent node launches which machine to use. Are there plans to put that implicit mechanism into an explicit tag for include, too? It would be extremely helpful since the current situation is sub-optimal for hierarchical launch structures.

**Comment by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) on 2017-06-16**:
Maybe Thomas is right. I tried @Girmi suggestion but still run local launch file on my local computer, not remote.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found a way and tested it in ROS-Indigo:

1. The Problem:

the  [`<node>`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node)-tag contains an attribute `machine` to set the machine on wich the node should run.

If you want to include a launch-file with the  [`<include>`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include)-tag and in this launchfile are some  [`<node>`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node)-tags, include didn't provide a machine-Attribute for easy passing this information -> so  normally only static launchfiles are possible.

2. **Solution**

Pass the machine with an [argument](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg) through the
 [`<include>`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include)-tag!

Here my version:

```
<include file=/path/to/my/launchfile.launch>
      <arg name="machine" value="the_machine" />
 </include>
```

and here the launchfile.launch:

```
<launch>
 <arg name="machine" />     
 <node pkg="mypkg" name="mypkgname" machine="$(arg machine)">
</node>
</launch>
```

Arguments are discribed [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg)

---

Originally posted by [dannyknoll](https://answers.ros.org/users/10911/dannyknoll/) with karma: 21 on 2015-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone is still looking for an answer, I think currently the most elegant solution is:

```
<launch>
        <include file="local_nodes.launch" />

        <group>
            <machine name="remote_machine" address="1.2.3.4" default="true" />
            <include file="remote_nodes.launch" />
        </group>
</launch>
```

Tested with ROS Kinectic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit:
Apparently the machine tag doesn't apply to a specific group, but to any nodes/includes that come after it. So the order in which the tags are defined is important!

---

Originally posted by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) with karma: 111 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cellard0or](https://answers.ros.org/users/27123/cellard0or/) on 2017-04-12**:
Thanks, this helped very much. Without this workaround I would have to adapt the structure of dozens of  launch files. However, the  tag is not working here as nodes launched after the group still appear on remote. One has to define a new machine with the local address again afterwards. Ugly.

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2020-11-19**:
The group tag doesn't work for me. Neither the code above (with default removed and user and env-loader added) nor the simply using the  tag without the machine name (but within group) work. I'm on 18.04/Melodic, but shouldn't make a difference ?